# How to Open a URL in New Activity's Webview by passing intent

Tags: android, json, webview

Here I am Opening the URL which is fetched from JSON Feed in the Browser. I need to open the URL in Another new activity's webview. I Created New Activity where I kept webview too. But the Intent is not passing the String

Here is the Current Code of Opening the URL in Browser

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CourseViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Course course = courseList.get(position);
    holder.textViewCoursename.setText(course.getCoursename());
    holder.textViewcoursedescshort.setText(course.getCoursedescshort());
    holder.textViewcourserating.setText(course.getCourserating());

    Glide.with(context).load(course.getCourseimg()).into(holder.imageView);    

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(course.getCourseurl()));
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `i.putExtra(KEY, yourURL)` instead of `i.setData`. You will need a key for that value.

And you will get it by the key in the new activity :

```
String url = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(KEY);
```

Comment: Where I have to Mention KEY Value in my Current Activity?

Comment: KEY value is a string to know what you are passing throught the intent, juste use for example "course_url". More info there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: I'm getting this error.. I Attached the Image too.. https://imgur.com/a/hl9po   `Error:(61, 27) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(CourseAdapter,Class<WebActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CourseAdapter cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CourseAdapter cannot be converted to Context)`

Comment: Here is the Code of WebActivity.java .. https://imgur.com/a/LyQYo

Comment: It is clear, the constructor need a context as first argument, your coursadapter is not one. You need to use your current activity, like MainActivity.this.